# Permission denied error while writing to a file on D: in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to complete this assignment but I get the error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\Temperatures.txt'

is there something I am doing wrong here?

I have tried multiple changes and keep getting the same result.

## Create Class

```
class tempearutefile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
    def set_filename(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
    def get_filename(self):
        return self.__filename
    def calculateAverage(self, num1,num2,num3):
        try:
            total = num1+ num2+ num3
            average = total/3
            return average
        # exception errors
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
        except IOError as err:
            print(err)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
def main():
    try:
        #Getting input from the users
        num1=float(input("Please enter your first value: "))
        num2=float(input("Please enter your second value: "))
        num3=float(input("Please enter your third value: "))
        #Creating temperatue file
        test_file = open('D:\\Temperatures.txt', 'w')
        #writing input informatin to the file
        test_file.write(str(num1) + '\n')
        test_file.write(str(num2) + '\n')
        test_file.write(str(num3) + '\n')
        #closing file
        test_file.close()
        temp1 = tempearutefile(test_file)
        average = temp1.calculateAverage (float(num1),float(num2),float(num3))
        print("your average temperature is:", average)
        # exception errors
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
    except IOError as err:
        print(err)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    #Call to main
main()
```

Expecting an average temperature from 3 inputs.

Comment: Check if you have correct permissions for: `D:\Temperatures.txt`

Comment: Please provice a [mcve], with focus on "minimal". Most of your code is not related to the problem. Basically, you could reduce it to 1 line

Comment: Are you on Windows? (IDLE is quite uncommon on Windows, I'd say) Do you have a D: drive? Can you save files on D: by yourself, e.g. a Word file? Does the file already exist or not? Who is the owner of that file? What permissions are set? Is there a directory called `Temperatures.txt`?

Comment: Yes I am actually using windows. The instructor recommend we use it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide answers to all the questions I asked you in the comment.

Comment: I tried in pycharm and IDLE both, it seemed working to me. Check if you have a D: drive, and also check if you have permission to write there (If its your system, then you should have it).
If D: is not there, try saving in C drive. Create a folder in C, and save there.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Discussions of editors and IDE are defined as off-topic.  See the help files.  And, as you said, not relevant to file.write failing.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: I don't think a comment about an IDE is disallowed. A question and an answer would be closed as off-topic, I totally agree.